# C# MSAL Token Cache - No Cached Access Token (Always Acquires New Token)

Tags: c#, azure, access-token, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

I've built a .Net Desktop application, c# and I'm testing out the MSAL + token cache functionality for logging into an Azure AD app using `PublicClientApplicationBuilder` and `StorageCreationPropertiesBuilder` (Windows).

I've followed the guidance on the MS MSAL docs pages and can acquire an access token successfully. The token is stored in the token cache on my machine but I see a new access token is being acquired every time I call `app.AcquireTokenSilent`. The refresh token is being used by MSAL, I don't have to interactively re-sign in each time I call `AcquireTokenSilent`, just a new token is always acquired/cached.

Checking the logs available (LogMetrics obj) I see the following entries:

> MSAL 4.46.0.0 MSAL.Desktop 4.8 or later Windows 10 Enterprise [] [Clear] Clearing access token cache data.

and then eventually:

> [LogMetricsFromAuthResult] Cache Refresh Reason: NoCachedAccessToken

This results in a new access token being acquired every time I run `app.AcquireTokenSilent`.

When I check the token cache I can see the access token + id + refresh token are all saved correctly and are updated accordingly post acquisition.

Has anyone experienced similar behavior? My understanding is `app.AcquireTokenSilent` should return the valid/active access token inside the cache and only acquire a new one silently if the token has or is about to expire.